# It compiles and run, but when I press any button it gives me an error message. Thanks

Tags: java

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    class cwp2
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            MyFrame F1 = new MyFrame();
        }
    }

    class MyFrame extends JFrame 
    {
        MyFrame()
        {
        //main window
            setSize(480,300);
        MyPanel mainpanel = new MyPanel();
            mainpanel.setLocation(300,300);
        add(mainpanel);
            setTitle("Super Screen & Keyboard");
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setVisible(true);
    }
    }

   class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        private JTextArea screen;
        private JButton spacebar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

        MyPanel()   
    {
        //text screen 
        JTextArea screen = new JTextArea();
        screen.setColumns(40);
        screen.setRows(9);
        screen.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        screen.setLineWrap(true);

        //buttons and actions
        spacebar = new JButton("spacebar");
        spacebar.addActionListener(this);
        a = new JButton("a");
        a.addActionListener(this);
        b = new JButton("b");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        c = new JButton("c");
        c.addActionListener(this);
        d = new JButton("d");
        d.addActionListener(this);
        e = new JButton("e");
        e.addActionListener(this);
        f = new JButton("f");
        f.addActionListener(this);
        g = new JButton("g");
        g.addActionListener(this);
        h = new JButton("h");
        h.addActionListener(this);
        i = new JButton("i");
        i.addActionListener(this);
        j = new JButton("j");
        j.addActionListener(this);
        k = new JButton("k");
        k.addActionListener(this);
        l = new JButton("l");
        l.addActionListener(this);
        m = new JButton("m");
        m.addActionListener(this);
        n = new JButton("n");
        n.addActionListener(this);
        o = new JButton("o");
        o.addActionListener(this);
        p = new JButton("p");
        p.addActionListener(this);
        q = new JButton("q");
        q.addActionListener(this);
        r = new JButton("r");
        r.addActionListener(this);
        s = new JButton("s");
        s.addActionListener(this);
        t = new JButton("t");
        t.addActionListener(this);
        u = new JButton("u");
        u.addActionListener(this);
        v = new JButton("v");
        v.addActionListener(this);
        w = new JButton("w");
        w.addActionListener(this);
        x = new JButton("x");
        x.addActionListener(this);
        y = new JButton("y");
        y.addActionListener(this);
        z = new JButton("z");
        z.addActionListener(this);

        add(q);
        add(w);
        add(e);
        add(r);
        add(t);
        add(y);
        add(u);
        add(i);
        add(o);
        add(p);
        add(a);
        add(s);
        add(d);
        add(f);
        add(g);
        add(h);
        add(j);
        add(k);
        add(l);
        add(z);
        add(x);
        add(c);
        add(v);
        add(b);
        add(n);
        add(m);
        add(spacebar);
        add(screen);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == spacebar)
        {
            screen.append(" ");
        }

        else 
        {
            screen.append(e.getSource.getActionCommand());
        }
    }
```

When I press a button I get an error message on the command prompt.

Comment: What is the error message....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
e.getSource.getActionCommand()
```

The `getSource()` method returns an object of Object type, and Object has no `getActionCommand()` method.

It's simply

```
e.getActionCommand()
```

Since e is an ActionEvent variable, and this type in fact has this method.

---

Suggestion: next time you have a similar question, please show all complete error or exception messages and indicate in a comment which line throws it.

---

**Edit**

Your new problem is due to your *shadowing* the screen variable.

Your code:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {  
    private JTextArea screen;  // screen declared here
    private JButton spacebar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

    MyPanel() {
      //text screen 
      JTextArea screen = new JTextArea();  // but re-declared here!
```

This means that the screen variable that you initialize in the constructor is a local variable and not the field that was declared in the class.

This can be fixed by not redeclaring the variable:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {  
    private JTextArea screen;  // screen declared here
    private JButton spacebar,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

    MyPanel() {
      //text screen 
      // JTextArea screen = new JTextArea();  // but re-declared here!
      screen = new JTextArea();   // note the difference?
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still does not work.

Comment: The error message that appears on the command prompt when I press a button is as follows:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MyPanel.actionPerformed(cwp2.java:141)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown

Comment: Etc, etc...it does not let me copy all the error here

Comment: @user2975205: I'm guessing that this is a *different* error message? Please indicate which line is throwing the NPE.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels He is creating `screen` as a local variable to the constructor, when it should just be assigned to the class variable. `screen` is `null`, and hence the NPE.

Comment: Any hope for my poor cause?

Comment: @user2975205: yes, see edit to answer.

Comment: it is my first time here, i do appreciate your help guys

Comment: Guys you are amazing thanks so much I spent hours and hours trying to figure out what was wrong :)